# Permutation cost

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am given a permutation of the set {1,2,...,n}. I have to sort this permutation only by swapping numbers situated on succesive positions with a minimum total cost. The cost of swapping the elements x,y, situated on succesive position is min(x,y).

For example if I have the permutation 3,1,2,4 the total minimum cost is 3.
Because I do these steps ( (x,y) means swapping x with y):

- (3,1),2,4 results 1,3,2,4 with the cost min(1,3)=1
- 1,(3,2),4 results 1,2,3,4 with the cost min(2,3)=2

Total cost is 3.

I tried brute force, by swapping the minimum cost unsorted pair, until there are no unsorted pairs, but this method is obviously not fast enough.

My question is, how do I find the minimum cost of sorting given my conditions?

Comment: There is no question here. You've told us what you're doing. What do you WANT to do that is different from what you're doing? BTW, +1 on your English...it's very good. :)

Comment: @JonathanM, the question is obvious: what is the most optimal solution?

Comment: @user1385303, can you give an example where bubble-sort gives a not-optimal result? It seems to me if you just swap greedily you get the minimum cost (but I need to prove it).

Comment: @Shahbaz, but if the rules are that you must only swap successive elements, there is no other way to do the sort. If there's only one way, it must be both the best and worst way to do it. So where's the question?

Comment: @Shahbaz - it wasn't obvious to me, either. Even if it were, it is still worth encouraging OP to create his post in the form of a question.

Comment: @JonathanM, it seems so. I haven't proven yet if the order of the operations makes any difference.

Answer (score 5):

The number of succesive-number swaps to sort a sequence is equal to the number of pairs in reversed order.

For example

```
6 1 3 2 4 5
```

Pairs in reversed order are listed below:

```
(6,1) (6,3) (6,2) (6,4) (6,5) (3,2)
```

so

the operations to sort the sequence are:

```
swap(6,1) 1 6 3 2 4 5
swap(6,3) 1 3 6 2 4 5
swap(6,2) 1 3 2 6 4 5
swap(6,4) 1 3 2 4 6 5
swap(6,5) 1 3 2 4 5 6
swap(3,2) 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

So the operation is determinate(unless you do some useless operations).

You only need to count all pairs (x,y) in reversed order, and sum up min(x,y).

Comment: Yes, and this pairs are called as inversions. And you have just demonstrated insertion sort.

Comment: And checking all pairs is a brute force n-squared solution

Comment: No it isn't because you can use Binary indexed trees or Interval trees to get a better O(n*log n) solution :) .

Answer (score 1):

This algoritm sounds like [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). Insertion sort based on eliminating inversions in the permutation. And you task is to eliminate inversions as in insertion sort. As you've already known sorted array hasn't any inversions.

The time complexity of insertion sort algorithm is O(n+d), where n is the number of elements and d - is the  number of inversions.

The maximum number of inversions in permutation is n*(n-1)/2, and the minimum is 0.

You can use modificated [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) to find number of inversions in array in O(n*lg n).

Comment: An insertion sort allows you to move an element more than 1 index at a time. This is just a bubble sort. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: @Jonathan M, it depends on realization. Usually we use swapping for moving. And the number of swaps depends on number of inversions d(i) for this element i. If you even use linked list you need d(i) time to find the insertion place.